# Android: How to avoid downloading a file again which is currently downloading

Tags: java, android, android-file, android-download-manager

```
public class RemoteApkInstaller {
    public void install(String url) {
        listenForDownloadCompleteEvent();
        downloadApk(url);
    }

    private void listenForDownloadCompleteEvent() {
        IntentFilter downloadCompleteIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        downloadCompleteReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (isInitiatedApkDownload(intent)) {
                    if (isDownloadSuccessful()) {
                        handleDownloadComplete();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.download_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        logFailure();
                    }
                    context.unregisterReceiver(downloadCompleteReceiver);
                }
            }
        };
        context.registerReceiver(downloadCompleteReceiver, downloadCompleteIntentFilter);
    }

    private void downloadApk(String url) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        apkFileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        if (isFileExistsInDownloadDir()) {
            handleDownloadComplete();
            return;
        }
        DownloadManager.Request request = getDownloadRequest(uri);
        downloadID = getDownloadManager().enqueue(request);
    }
    private boolean isFileExistsInDownloadDir() {
        File directory = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File file = new File(directory, apkFileName);
        return file.exists();
    }

    private void handleDownloadComplete() {
        doOperationsOnDownloadedPackage()
        installApk(context);
    }

    private void doOperationsOnDownloadedPackage() {
        PackageManager packageManager= getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        String appName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        ...
    }

    private void installApk(Context context) {
        File directory = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File file = new File(directory, apkFileName);

        String mimeType = downloadID == UNSET_DOWNLOAD_ID ? MIME_TYPE_FOR_APK_FILE : getDownloadManager().getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadID);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "my.package.fileProvider", file);
            installIntent.setDataAndType(apkUri, mimeType);
            installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            context.startActivity(installIntent);
        } else {
            Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, mimeType);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically when I click a weblink, an instance of this class is created and the install() method invoked. The problem is when I click the weblink again while the previous download is still only partially complete. I'm trying to check the downloads folder to determine if file already exists and if so, proceed with next set of action. 
Even if the previous download is partially complete, the flag is true so in this case I'm executing the doOperationsOnDownloadedPackage() method on an apk file which is not 100% downloaded and I see crashes obviously.
What I'm looking for is a way to avoid initiating a repeat download if the same file is currently downloading.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Save a flag to shared preferences.

Comment: If there is any other way possible, that'd be welcome. Shared preference flag is fine too but then there are too many edge cases like if user cancels the download, error in download etc for which I have to keep track of updating the flag else the next download will not happen.

Comment: Just an in memory flag could work too.  In your activity or fragment just set a boolean and then don't respond to the click event until the download is complete.  If it were a regular layout and not a webview I'd say disable the button but that probably isn't an option.